# Sending a string of JSON as a POST to asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

**I am attempting to send a string to my web api like this:**

```
public IList<Product> GetProducts(string myString)
{
    IList<Product> retVal = null;
    using (var client = GetClient())
    {
        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(myString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        // HTTP POST
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("api/products", httpContent).Result;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

**In my ProductsController my action method looks like this:**

```
// POST: api/products/filter
[HttpPost("filter")]
public IList<Product> Filter(string filter)
{

}
```

For some reason the filter param keeps coming in as null. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should decorate parameter with [FromBody] attribute as post will not take value from url I suspect

Comment: Hmm I tried it with FromBody and still null. Should content-type be application/json if sending a string of json?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like youre posting to api/products, not api/products/filter.
Signature for the method should be as Vidas says with the from body attribute, but posted to the correct url.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/products/filter")
Public ilist<product>  Filter([FromBody] string filter)
{...}
```

While the route isnt specifically necessary, it can help you specify the url you are working with!

Comment: Sorry I apolgize. At the top of the products controller I have api/controllerName specified.

Comment: My observation was based on your getproducts method, but looks like you got it sorted in the end which is the main thing